# Can we use Cloud storage in flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, google-cloud-storage

I am not able find the correct answer as if one can tell me if yes then how and if no then what is the preferred database just like firebase that integrate with all the three android web and IOS fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`firebase.dart` package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) that for a long time has been usable on the web. There's even an [example page](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/firebase/example/storage) in the repo.

Right now it's in a state of limbo though, as the same functionality is being added to the [`firebase_storage` package](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/firebase_storage-library.html) in the FlutterFire repo, but web support hasn't been completed there yet.